what if a feature that is described as "optional" isn't really optional?
If within the specifications, a certain feature is described as "optional", but the patent examiner determines that it is required for the invention to work, what can be done at this point?
Can the applicant modify the patent by simply erasing the word "optional"?

You can't change the spec, but you can edit the claims. The claims are what matter.

You often see granted patents with claims that are far narrower than what is described in the specification. This happens because the examiner won't grant the broad claims for one reason or another. In this case, I don't believe the examiner will allow you to remove the word "optional" from the spec, but you could edit the claims such that the optional feature is required. I am not a lawyer so it would be best for you to discuss this with your lawyer.
